# How to use firebase onSnapshot in chain using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use firebase's onSnapshot function sequentially. A situation where I want to apply this is given below.

Scenario:

There are 2 collections in firestore. `Employees` and `Projects`. In the `Employees` collection, the docs are storing the details of employees. And it also stores the IDs of `Projects` docs on which that particular employee is working. In `Projects` collection, the detail of projects is stored.

Goal:

First, I have to fetch the data from `Employees` collection related to a specific employee. Then, from the fetched employee data, I will have the project IDs on which he/she is working on. So, from that ID I need to fetch the project details. So, when any information related to project or employee changes, the data on screen should also change in real-time.

Issue:

I tried to write a nested code. But it works realtime only for employee data. It doesn't change when the project detail is updated. Something like this...

```
admin.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
    if (check_field(admin.auth().currentUser)) {
        await db.collection('Employees').doc(admin.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot(snap => {
            ...
            let project_details = new Promise(resolve => {
                let projects = [];
                for (let i in snap.data().projects_list) {
                    db.collection('Projects').doc(snap.data().projects_list[i]).onSnapshot(prj_snap => {
                        let obj = prj_snap.data();
                        obj['doc_id'] = prj_snap.id;
                        projects.push(obj);
                    });
                }
                resolve(projects);
            });

            Promise.all([project_details]).then(items => {
                ...
                // UI updation
            });
            ...
        });
    }
});
```

What is the correct way for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually proposing a pretty complex dataflow scenario. I would approach this as a multi-step problem. Your goal is essentially:

1. If there is a user, listen in realtime for the list of project ids for that user.
2. For each project id, listen in realtime for details about that project.
3. (presumably) Clean up listeners that are no longer relevant.

So I would tackle it something like this:

```
let uid;
let employeeUnsub;
let projectIds = [];
let projectUnsubs = {};
let projectData = {};

const employeesRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Employees');
const projectsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Projects');

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  // if there is already a listener but the user signs out or changes, unsubscribe
  if (employeeUnsub && (!user || user.uid !== uid)) {
    employeeUnsub();
  }

  if (user) {
    uid = user.uid;
    // subscribe to the employee data and trigger a listener update on changes
    employeeUnsub = employeesRef.doc(uid).onSnapshot(snap => {
      projectIds = snap.get('projects_list');
      updateProjectListeners();
    });
  }
});

function updateProjectListeners() {
  // get a list of existing projects being listened already
  let existingListeners = Object.keys(projectUnsubs);
  for (const pid of existingListeners) {
    // unsubscribe and remove the listener/data if no longer in the list
    if (!projectIds.includes(pid)) {
      projectUnsubs[pid]();
      delete projectUnsubs[pid];
      delete projectData[pid];
      render();
    }
  }

  for (const pid of projectIds) {
    // if we're already listening, nothing to do so skip ahead
    if (projectUnsubs[pid]) { continue; }
    // subscribe to project data and trigger a render on change
    projectUnsubs[pid] = projectsRef.doc(pid).onSnapshot(snap => {
      projectData[pid] = snap.data);
      render();
    });
  }
}

function render() {
  const out = "<ul>\n";
  for (const pid of projectIds) {
    if (!projectData[pid]) {
      out += `<li class="loading">Loading...</li>\n`;
    } else {
      const project = projectData[pid];
      out += `<li>${project.name}</li>`;
    }
  }
  out += "</ul>\n";
}
```

The above code does what you're talking about (and in this case the `render()` function just returns a string but you could do whatever you want to actually manipulate DOM / display data there).

It's a lengthy example, but you're talking about a pretty sophisticated concept of essentially joining realtime data dynamically as it changes. Hope this gives you some guidance on a way forward!

Comment: Great! Thank you. You have cleared my doubts. I have tried doing this way and it works. :)